# run jmeter test using jenkins

Tags: maven, plugins, jenkins, jmeter

i was asked by my boss to make the jemeter tests runs on Jenkins so other employees can run the tests in Jenkins without install and learn any other tools
i have read that in order to make jenkins runs the jmeter test then i have first to use maven. i installed maven and download the jmeter maven plugging. here i stopped because i don't know where to put the plugging and how to use it. and since am totally new to maven i used so resources to help me. they say that i have to put:

put where i should i put it i could not figure out.
please if you have any information that can help me i will appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Read this blog:

- https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/01/automating-jmeter-tests-maven-jenkins/
- http://youtu.be/9WkuapS3Ki0?a

And reference doc of jenkins and maven (at least what is used by blog and install procedure)